# c++ - get outermost edge in image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

After applying edge detection, I have a set of images that i want to further process,

[image: here is a sample,]
Is there any advice if I want to only get the outermost boundary, in this case,   I only want to the shape of the human, 
I wish to take away the eye, nose, ear, background grass, edges detected in the image. is OpenCV gonna help?

Comment: before being able to decide, whether something (an edge) is inside or outside of something, you'll have to group edges to contours.

Answer (score 2):

No vision algorithm can guess what a human looks like if you don't provide models, either as sample images, or as some kind of structural description built into code.

In the case of this edge map, you will need a way to relate edge pieces to a potential silhouette edge, taking into account clutter and occlusion. (Note that using edge detection is probably a very bad idea to begin with, it spoils a lot of useful information; better use segmentation)

So you have a case of deformable template matching, in difficult conditions. My best advice: if you are inexperienced, drop it.